# count rows until value changes then continue counting for the next value in dplyr

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, count

I want to do a survival probability in R using the run times of a cell is in a specific state (1, 2, or 3). So, I am trying to count the number of rows that a cell stays in a specific state in different IDs. I just don't want the total count of states, but I want the number of times it occurs before it changes over the course of time.

This is a representative dataframe:

```
structure(list(id = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B"
), time = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", 
"11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21"
), state = c("1", "3", "3", "3", "2", "2", "2", "3", "3", "3", 
"2", "2", "2", "1", "1", "3", "2", "1", "3", "3", "3")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-21L))
  id time state
1  A    1     1
2  A    2     3
3  A    3     3
4  A    4     3
5  A    5     2
6  A    6     2
 
df2 <- df %>%
  group_by (id) %>%
  summarise (statechange = count(state))

  id    statechange$x $freq      
1 A     1                 3
2 A     2                 6
3 A     3                 6
4 B     1                 1
5 B     2                 1
6 B     3                 4
```

Ideally, the result should be:

```
id  from  statechange   freq
A   NA  1       1
A   1   3       3
A   3   2       3
A   2   3       3
A   3   2       3
A   2   1       2
B   NA  3       1
B   3   2       1
B   2   1           1
B   1   2       3
```

where from is the original state before it changed and statechange is the ones that are being counted.

I don't know if I should use an ifelse statement for counts, or if there is another way to achieve this. Let me know if anything is not clear and I greatly appreciate help!

edit: changed the question to include the original state in the resulting df.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use rle to get your result. However, vased on your example data I get a different result than what you posted as expected output.

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  summarize(statechange = as.numeric(rle(state)[[2]]),
            freq = rle(state)[[1]]) %>%
  ungroup()

# A tibble: 10 x 3
   id    statechange  freq
   <chr>       <dbl> <int>
 1 A               1     1
 2 A               3     3
 3 A               2     3
 4 A               3     3
 5 A               2     3
 6 A               1     2
 7 B               3     1
 8 B               2     1
 9 B               1     1
10 B               3     3
```

Comment: thank you! I just manually did my expected output and it seems like I missed one row. When I tried your code, the id column doesn't show for me, so I only have statechange and freq.

Comment: Is there also a way to get the original state before it changed? Thanks

Comment: The id should definitely be there. Are you sure it was missing? If so, please provide the data and the exact code you were running - just update your question. Does the id is also missing if you use my code with your example data?

Comment: What do you mean with „original state before it changed“? What is the original state and where do we see how/when it changed? Please update your question with the expected output.

Comment: Hi, I copy-pasted exactly your code. I did not change anything. Is it because your output is a tibble? Mine is a dataframe. I also edited now the question. Thanks

Comment: Ok, I used a new instance of R and now it works. I am not sure if one of the packages that are loaded on the R instance I tried the code interfered with tidyverse.

Comment: That could be. In that case make sure you pay attention to the warning messages when loading the packages and what conflicts may happen. In that case it could also help to make the packages clear in the code, e.g. do dplyr::group_by instead of just group_by.

Comment: Also if the solution works, please consider accepting the answer so that others can benefit from it.